# How to define and use typings for a given .js script without JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, typescript-typings

Is it currently possible to have some file `foo.js` outside of a regular JavaScript npm package and without a `js/tsconfig.json` file, but still make use of a `foo.d.ts` declaration file?

The goal is for VS Code to propose help based on the type information from the `foo.d.ts` file without having to add type information as JSDoc.

I am using TypeScript 4.0.3, and currently types are not picked up when defined next to my script.

Answer (score 0):

What if you specify `foo.d.ts` through the `"types"` entry in the `package.json` file?

Like this:

```
  "types": "js/foo.d.ts",
```